# How to query a TempView in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have create a tempview as such as:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_test")
```

However, when I run the following command it doesn't work

```
%sql select top 10 * from table_test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```sql
%sql select * from table_test limit 10;
```

`top 10` is more specific to sql server and not the sql engine being used by your notebooks.

Comment: what derivative of sql language is spark using ?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg Spark is mostly similar to hiveql and you may find the current sql reference here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html